# Pyspark CountVectorizer and Word Frequency in a corpus

Tags: python, pyspark, text-mining

I'm currently studying a text corpus. 
Let's say that I cleaned my verbatims and that I have the following pyspark DataFrame :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(0, ["a", "b", "c"]),
                            (1, ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"])],
                            ["label", "raw"])
df.show()

+-----+---------------+
|label|            raw|
+-----+---------------+
|    0|      [a, b, c]|
|    1|[a, b, b, c, a]|
+-----+---------------+
```

I now want to implement a CountVectorizer. So, I used `pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer` as follows :

```
cv = CountVectorizer(inputCol="raw", outputCol="vectors")
model = cv.fit(df)
model.transform(df).show(truncate=False)

+-----+---------------+-------------------------+
|label|raw            |vectors                  |
+-----+---------------+-------------------------+
|0    |[a, b, c]      |(3,[0,1,2],[1.0,1.0,1.0])|
|1    |[a, b, b, c, a]|(3,[0,1,2],[2.0,2.0,1.0])|
+-----+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Now, I would also like to get the vocabulary that the CountVectorizer selected, **as well as** the corresponding word frequencies in the corpus. 
 Using `cvmodel.vocabulary` only provides the vocabulary list :

```
voc = cvmodel.vocabulary
voc
[u'b', u'a', u'c']
```

I would like to get something like that :

```
voc = {u'a':3,u'b':3,u'c':2}
```

Would you have any idea to do such a things?

**Edit**:

 I am using Spark 2.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling `cv.fit()` returns a `CountVectorizerModel`, which (AFAIK) stores the vocabulary but it does not store the counts. The vocabulary is property of the model (it needs to know what words to count), but the counts are a property of the DataFrame (not the model). You can apply the transform function of the fitted model to get the counts for any DataFrame.

That being said, here are two ways to get the output you desire.

**1. Using Existing Count Vectorizer Model**

You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.explode()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) to gather the entire corpus into a single row. For illustrative purposes, let's consider a new DataFrame `df2` which contains some words unseen by the fitted `CountVectorizer`:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df2 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([(0, ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y"]),
                            (1, ["a", "b", "b", "c", "a"])],
                            ["label", "raw"])

combined_df = (
    df2.select(f.explode('raw').alias('col'))
      .select(f.collect_list('col').alias('raw'))
)
combined_df.show(truncate=False)
#+------------------------------+
#|raw                           |
#+------------------------------+
#|[a, b, c, x, y, a, b, b, c, a]|
#+------------------------------+
```

Then use the fitted model to transform this into counts and collect the results:

```python
counts = model.transform(combined_df).select('vectors').collect()
print(counts)
#[Row(vectors=SparseVector(3, {0: 3.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 2.0}))]
```

Next `zip` the counts and the vocabulary together and use the `dict` constructor to get the desired output:

```python
print(dict(zip(model.vocabulary, counts[0]['vectors'].values)))
#{u'a': 3.0, u'b': 3.0, u'c': 2.0}
```

As you correctly pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255356/pyspark-countvectorizer-and-word-frequency-in-a-corpus/50259673#comment87598686_50259673), this will only consider the words that are part of the `CountVectorizerModel`'s vocabulary. Any other words will be ignored. Hence we don't see any entries for `"x"` or `"y"`.

**2. Use DataFrame aggregate functions**

Or you can skip the `CountVectorizer` and get your output using a `groupBy()`. This is a more generic solution in that it will give the counts for *all* words in the DataFrame, not just those in the vocabulary:

```python
counts = df2.select(f.explode('raw').alias('col')).groupBy('col').count().collect()
print(counts)
#[Row(col=u'x', count=1), Row(col=u'y', count=1), Row(col=u'c', count=2), 
# Row(col=u'b', count=3), Row(col=u'a', count=3)]
```

Now simply use a `dict` comprehension:

```python
print({row['col']: row['count'] for row in counts})
#{u'a': 3, u'b': 3, u'c': 2, u'x': 1, u'y': 1}
```

Here we have the counts for `"x"` and `"y"` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So the main difference between **1.** and **2.** is that **1.** would consider only the words that are part of the CountVectorizer's vocabulary whereas **2.** will keep any word of the corpus?

Comment: @plalanne that is exactly right. I have updated the answer with an example that demonstrates this more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using RDD:

```
total_counts=df_trans[['vectors']].rdd
        .map(lambda row: row['vectors'].toArray())
        .reduce(lambda x,y: [x[i]+y[i] for i in range(len(y))])

dict(zip(model.vocabulary, total_counts))
```